# Testing Angularjs app-How to fetch the text in object having ng-repeat property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Below is the angularjs code , I need to use ng repeater locator and fetch the value "Number: 12345"  in class ng binding. without using xpath

```
<tr class="auto-row ng-scope" ng-class="{success : row1Checked}" ng-repeat="aut in aut">
  <td style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" colspan="2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input class="ng-pristine " id="row1" type="checkbox" ng-model="row1Checked"><span class="ng-binding" id="mq-auto">Car Number</span><br>
            <span id="mq-auto" style="color: rgb(168, 168, 168); padding-left: 0px;"><small class="ng-binding">Number: 12345</small></span>
          </label>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Below is the test code I used

```
var aut = element.all(by.repeater('aut in aut'));
var text = aut.get(0).getText();
```

Comment: Better way to create any jsfiddle.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of your controller code? By the way your repeater has the same name as your repeated inside your ng-repeat, that's a bit confusing

Comment: @Zonedark :- I tried using the property value to fetch the data but it did not work, I need the JavaScript code to test the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var aut = element.all(by.repeater('aut in aut'));` would refer to every `tr` element in the repeater, but you need to get to an inner element containing the desired number. If this is something you need to do for every row, use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var aut = element.all(by.repeater('aut in aut'));
var numbers = aut.map(function (row) {
    return row.element(by.id("mq-auto")).getText();
});

expect(numbers).toEqual(["Number: 12345", "Number: 1231234", ... ]);
```

Comment: :- i am getting following error message   "Failed: numbers.getText is not a function"

Comment: @DilipReddy oops, sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First for better readability you should not use `aut in aut` but something more descriptive like `automobile in automobiles`.

All the classes suffixed by `ng-` are automaticaly injected by angular so do not try to write it in your code.

And if you have something like that in your controller :

```
$scope.automobiles = [
  { number: 12345 },
];
```

and something like that in the view it should do the trick :

```
<div ng-repeat="automobile in automobiles">
  <span>{{ 'Car Number: ' + automobile.number }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: :- Code is already developed I don't have control over it , I need to test the app where I just want to validate the data 'number: 12345'.

Comment: This is about how to locate the repeater and inner elements in protractor while end-to-end testing an AngularJS application.